# Applying a lower bound threshold on a list

Tags: list-manipulation

Consider the following list

```
list={0,0,0,10^-18,10^-15,10^-12,10^-10,1,1}
```

How can I apply a threshold on the list that will give a lower bound for the values. For example

```
ApplyThreshold[list,10^-12];
```

will yield an outcome of

```
   {10^-12,10^-12,10^-12,10^-12,10^-12,10^-12,10^-10,1,1}
```

and

```
ApplyThreshold[list,10^-9];
```

will yield an outcome of

```
   {10^-9,10^-9,10^-9,10^-9,10^-9,10^-9,10^-9,1,1}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [`Clip`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Clip.html), [`Ramp`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Ramp.html)  or [`Max`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Max.html):

```
Clip[list, {10^-9, ∞}]
```

> {1/1000000000, 1/1000000000, 1/1000000000, 1/1000000000, 
>   1/1000000000, 1/1000000000, 1/1000000000, 1, 1}

```
Ramp[list - 10^-9] + 10^-9 === Max[#, 10^-9] & /@ list === %
```

> True

**Timings:**

```
SeedRandom[1]
lst = RandomReal[1, 100000];

(r1 = Ramp[lst - 10^-9] + 10^-9 ;) // RepeatedTiming // First
```

> 0.00017

```
(r2 = Clip[lst , {10^-9, Infinity}];) // RepeatedTiming // First
```

> 0.000221

```
(r3 = Max[#, 10^-9] & /@ lst ;) // RepeatedTiming // First
```

> 0.129

```
(r4 = Map[crit[#, 1*10^-12] &, lst ];) // RepeatedTiming // First (* from Alexei's answer*)
```

> 0.185

```
r1 == r2 == r3 == r4
```

> True

Answer (score 2):

Try the following. This si your list:

```
lst = {0, 0, 0, 10^-18, 10^-15, 10^-12, 10^-10, 1, 1}
```

This function transforms any number to what you want:

```
crit[x_, y_] := If[x >= y, x, y];
```

This applies it to the list:

```
Map[crit[#, 1*10^-12] &, lst]

(* {1/1000000000000, 1/1000000000000, 1/1000000000000, 1/1000000000000, \
1/1000000000000, 1/1000000000000, 1/10000000000, 1, 1}  *)
```

Here is another example of yours:

```
Map[crit[#, 1*10^-9] &, lst]

(*  {1/1000000000, 1/1000000000, 1/1000000000, 1/1000000000, \
1/1000000000, 1/1000000000, 1/1000000000, 1, 1}  *)
```

Have fun!

Answer (score 1):

You can do this succinctly with the `ReplaceAll (/.)` and `Condition (/;)` operators:

```
list /. x_ /; x < 10^-12 -> 10^-12
```